# Client side data encryption/decryption for rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, security, encryption

Users are sending messages to each other and publish private information for other users via rails app.

The goal is to secure the messages, so neither system admins, nor database leaks won't be able to compromise the data. Javascript client side encryption with recipient key, encrypted data is stored in the database and decrypted on recipient's side. Keys are not stored in the system.

Does is make sense? Is there a solution?
Thanks a lot!

Update: I mean asymmetric cryptography. Two keys for each user: one public for encryption, one private for decryption. And a password for the application itself. User logs in using his password, creates a message, which is encrypted client side with a recipients public key (stored in the system) and saved in the database. Recipient logs in using his password, then  enters his private key to decode messages. Decryption is also client side, private key is not sent to the server.

Comment: Only problem I see: if the keys are not stored in the system, how does the client keep hold of them? Local storage? Then I couldn't log into the system from two computers (or even browsers). Just a simple password? There's a danger of it being brute-forced. ...

Comment: @JoachimSauer I ment asymmetric cryptography. Public key can be stored in the system, because it cannot be used for decryption. Question updated

Comment: still, how will the *client* get (or keep) the private key? It will still need it to decrypt the data.

Comment: @Elder Joachim's argument sill holds. You have to store the private key.

Comment: Regarding update: so you want the user to "enter" the private key? As in "type in"? Those things are not exactly easy to remember, let alone type in correctly.

Comment: Even then, if you type it into a browser, how do you trust the web page? It's not safe against change by an attacker, nor by change of the system admin I presume.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes, user has to _type in_ the key. It a small cost for security. You keep your data and your key separately. If the system is hacked and the database is leaked, your data is not compromised, because your key is not stored there.

Comment: @JoachimSauer finally user can use a password manager, like lastpass.com. Storing the key next to the data makes little sense of using data encryption.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Use this http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/.
Especially look at the demo http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.com/sjcl/demo/

One thing to keep in mind, the only way for you to not store the keys is for the user's to derive them from a password ( which should not be the one they use for your site). This is fine and is what the above library does.However,if they forget the password, there is no helping them,

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what i'm looking for. AES is a symmetric algorithm, i'm looking for an asymmetric one, like RSA.

Comment: Ah, missed that. There is a a branch that supports asymmetric crypto https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/commits/ecc  .  In general, there are a bunch of javascript crypto libraries but almsot none of them are written by people who know anything about what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

On the client side, you can use [openpgp.js](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs). It's legit easy to use lib for creating keys, signing, encryption/decryption, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Might be one of the solutions.The jsbn library is a fast, portable implementation of large-number math in pure JavaScript, enabling public-key crypto and other applications on desktop and mobile browsers.

http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/

RSA Cryptography Demo http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/rsa2.html